# Accordion menu - active state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I've lately managed to make my accordion menu. I did everything besides this one thing I'm looking for help.

This is my accordion menu:

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="main_nav">
       <li><a href='#'>MAIN 1</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href='#'>SUB MENU</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                   <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
                   <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
                   <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
                   <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
                   <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
                   <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href='#'>SUB MENU</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                   <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href='#'>SUB MENU</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                   <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href='#'>SUB MENU</a>
               <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
                   <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href='#'>SUB MENU</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                   <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href='#'>MAIN 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .main_nav {
        width: 250px;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 40px 30px 25px 0;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    ul.main_nav {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    ul.main_nav li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    ul.main_nav li a {
        background-image: url('../images/acmenu_bg.png');
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        line-height: 10px;
        padding: 13px 10px;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        list-style: none;
    }

    ul.main_nav li a:hover {
        /* background-image: url('');  HOVER ?!*/
        color: #ef7b0b;
    }

    ul.main_nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: none;
    }

    ul.main_nav ul li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        clear: both;
    }

    ul.main_nav ul li a {
        background-image: url('../images/acmenu2_bg.png');
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        padding-left: 20px;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    ul.main_nav ul li a:hover {
        color: #dcdcdc;
        /* HOVER */
    }

    ul.main_nav ul li a:active {
        background-image: url('../images/acmenu1_bg.png');
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }

    ul.main_nav ul ul li a {
        background: #f6f6f6;
        color: #000;
        padding-left: 40px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    }

    ul.main_nav ul ul li a:hover {
        color: #ef7b0b;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.sidebar-wrapper ul li a').click(function(ev) {
    $('.sidebar-wrapper .sub-menu').not($(this).parents('.sub-menu')).slideUp();
    $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    $('.main_nav ul li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
});
```

[My accordion menu example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2897W/3/)

As you can see I've tried to write the code as simple as possible. There are 2 things I can't handle with:

1st. ) I made a hover background to my sub-menus (only) - when It's clicked sub-sub menu list is showing - I would like to have only sub-menu items to be hovered (with that orange gradient), not sub-sub menu items, because when you click on sub-sub menu item it takes active state from sub-menu item, remove it and assign for yourself. I have a problem fixing that. ?

2nd. ) It's related to sub sub menu items. I would like to have sub-menu item active (covered with orange gradient background) when I have active sub sub menu item clicked (which is orange underline). One more thing, I'd like it to be always collapsed if sub sub menu item is active.

If something is unclear to you or I wrote something wrong please correct me and do not hesitate to ask for more details.

I would really appreciate for your help.

Thank you. Greetings -
Chris

Comment: Just a comment: you may want to reconsider your styling on the sub-menu items. White text on a light gray background isn't easy to read.

Comment: use http://jsfiddle.net/ to share the code, so that people can play around and suggest a solution for you

Comment: add an id to your li sub-menu and then use js to add the class you want to it on the click of any of its children

Comment: I'm sorry for not posting my code in jsfiddle, I thought codepen is also okay :P
Here is a link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2897W/3/

@Caolan Evans - it's not about styling :P I know it doesn't fit but I want to make it's functionality better.

Answer (score 0):

While I definitely applaud the abstraction of your Javascript, which is almost always considered a benefit and a proper coding practice, it appears as though you may be sacrificing control of the elements themselves; this is most likely due to the fact that each of your menus (sub-menu, sub-sub-menu) share the same class ("sub-menu").

In order to gain greater control over your Javascript, it might be worth specifying distinct class names for each of the menu elements:

**Sub-Menu (class: sub-menu)**

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Sub-Sub-Menu (class: sub-menu)**

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
</ul>
```

By specifying distinct class names, you can determine what to do/not do when a certain element is accessed in the DOM, that is:

```
<ul class="sub-sub-menu">
    <li><a href='#'>SUB-SUB MENU</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Here is jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/2897W/3/

So all you suggesting is to just change the names of my sub menu and sub sub menus and change javascript code somehow ? Not to mention, my js skills are not yet good and I have a problems even with easy things like this one, this is why im asking for help :)

Comment: That's the general idea that I'm proposing. And have a look at my Javascript here (http://mikechabot.org/js/links.js), this controls the three big links on http://mikechabot.org/. 

As you might note, I'm obtaining the id of the DOM element via var id = $(this).prop("id"); And you could just as easily find some code on the internet to get the class of the element. And once you either have the class or id of the element, simply use an IF statement. If(class==="sub-sub-menu") do this, else, do something else. Does that make sense? If not, I could probably provide some code when I'm back at home.

Comment: Well, it does ring a bell but as a novice in programming and especially in javascript I believe I won't be able to write anything myself to make it work. I'm having a hard time to learn JS and browsing over the internet for the solution I didn't manage to find a proper solution :/

Comment: Any more suggestions ? Is it possible that you could help me to fix this javascript I wrote ? I managed to fix my 2nd problem but I can't handle with the 1st one.

Comment: Go ahead and post the updated jsfiddle, and I'll take a look. And exactly what's the 1st problem? I'm having trouble following the description. Just explicitly describe what you'd like to have happen.

Comment: Im sorry for a pretty long delay but I had no time to do this . But there it is I made something different:

http://jsfiddle.net/36qLK/

But this time it doesn't want to work and I have no idea how to add 3rd level to slide/toggle.